# How to specifically choose columns and rows from txt file and write it down on another txt file with python?

Tags: python, database

I am really new in python.
I am trying to read data from txt file and select some columns and rows from it then write it down onto a new txt file.

This is the example of my input data:

```
*ELEMENT_SOLID
$#   eid     pid      n1      n2      n3      n4      n5      n6      n7      n8
       1       1    2235    2237    1579    1565    2067    2067     596     596
       2       1    2238    2240    1525    1547    2073    2073     674     674
```

I just need to use the 3rd and 4th rows and I don't need the 3rd colum.

I have looked from many answered questions here but I still haven't figure it out how to solve this.

I hope you could help me with my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code reads the tabluar from file 'element_solid.dat' and saves it to 'element_solid2.dat' after it changed one element.**

If you want to save only a part of the array, try out the command
`np.savetxt('element_solid2.dat',data[0:1,3:6], fmt='%7.i')`

```
import numpy as np

#Main programm
#read array from file 'element_solid.dat'
data = np.loadtxt('element_solid.dat', skiprows=2)
print(data)

#change one number in data to see the difference
data[0,2]=0

#save array to file 'element_solid.dat' without header
np.savetxt('element_solid2.dat',data, fmt='%7.i')
```

In the following I will scatch **an other solution** (as requested in the comments), which is more flexible, but needs some more fine tuning:

```
with open(filename) as fil:
    for line in fil:
        if line=="\n":
            #skip empty line
            continue
        if line[0]=='#':
            #skip comment lines starting with #
            continue
        if line=="#LastLine":
            #stops searching the file when reaches this line
            break
        else:
            #play around with line.split() -> string to list
            #and fltList=[float(elem) for elem in line.split()]
            #fltList is a list of floatingpoint numbers
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Dutscke for your answer! It's really helpful.
Can I ask a followup question tho?
What if after the list of data then it follows with several rows of unwanted sentences, and then another important data again.
In short way I need to skip several rows again and then read another data. How can I do that?

Comment: Hello Mr. Masduki, if you liked my answer, please vote it up ;)